# Why will a lone pair from H2O not attack a C+ atom in elimination reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

In step three of reaction between H2SO4 and alcohol, why will the H2O attack the H atom instead of the C+ atom? they both have positive charge and in nucleophilic substitution reactions the c+ atom is attacked.
(Image taken from [chem guide](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alkenes/Synthesis_of_Alkenes/Alkenes_from_Dehydration_of_Alcohols#:%7E:text=The%20dehydration%20reaction%20of%20alcohols,phosphoric%20acid%2C%20at%20high%20temperatures.) )
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ce{H2O}$ attacks the $\ce{C+}$ atom, it will produce the original alcohol back. No chemical effect.